# Column or Cell restriction if the other cell or column is blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello masters/mentors/teachers
I'm having problem with my existing project. I'd like to try here if anyone can help me

Note: Timestamp is script coded

Column A

a Dropdown Cell (Not yet started, In Progress, Completed)

Column B

if Column A on the same row choose " In Progress ", the Column B will be having a timestamp (time start)

Column C

if Column A on the same row choose " Completed ", the Column C will be having a timestamp (time end)

My problem is sometimes people may forgot to put "In Progress" first and just proceed with "Completed".

Is there a way to restrict the column C Cell if the column B is blank ? therefore they can't proceed with "Completed" if the "In Progress" timestamp are not yet available and Column C will only get timestamp when Column B's no longer blank

Comment: If they've already "Completed" and they forgot to mark "In Progress", what is the user supposed to do?

Comment: they will put comment and i will edit hahaha, That's why I need help to lock those cell first or atleast have a popup message that they need to timestamp for starting the task first before putting a completed mark

Comment: You can add protections on cells or even set notes through your script. You could also use Browser.msgBox() to display a popup. There's lots that you can do. If you have any issues implementing, please post your attempt and we can try to help you.

Comment: may be you can add trigger onedit where:, 1. if column B has no time stamp, column A,  always give 'Not Yet Started' and column b and c protected, 2.if column B has time stamp and column C has No time stamp, column A always give 'In Progress' and column C protected, 3. if Column B and Column C have timestamp, so column A always give "Completed", this just an idea

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is setup a trigger onEdit that will check when a user select 'Completed' if there is a start date. If not the script revert back the dropdown to previous value and display a warning message.

To work you must setup the onEdit() as an installable trigger.

It will looks like :

```
function setupTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(YOUR_SHEET_ID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("control")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}

function control(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  var range = e.range;
  var rangeCol = range.getColumn();
  var rangeRow = range.getRow();
//  Logger.log(rangeCol)
  if(rangeCol == 1){
    var dateStart = range.getSheet().getRange(rangeRow,2).getValue();
    var selection = e.value;
//    Logger.log(dateStart);
//    Logger.log(selection);
    if(selection == 'Completed' && dateStart == ""){
      Logger.log('User select completed and the start date is empty');
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
      ui.alert('Please select In Progress before completed, satrt date can\'t be empty.');
      if(!e.oldValue){
        range.getSheet().getRange(rangeRow,rangeCol).clearContent();
      }else{
        range.getSheet().getRange(rangeRow,rangeCol).setValue(e.oldValue)
      }
    }else{
      Logger.log('Do nothing')
    }
  }else{
    Logger.log('Not good column');
  }
}
```

Install it :

1. Enter the sheet id on the place of YOUR_SHEET_ID.
2. Run the function setupTrigger()

I setup basic control on the start date but you can check if it is a date, if the value is older than now or not etc... it depends your need but this code give you the basic to implement the control you want.

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Using the methods from the Spreadsheet Service [1] and an installable onEdit trigger [2][3], I set up the following code that will run when someone edit your Spreadsheet, if any cell in A column is change to "Not yet started" it'll protect the column C cell in that row from being edited (for anyone besides you). If the cell in A column is change to "In Progress" it'll remove the protection created before:

```
function onEditFunction(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var value = e.value;

  if(col == 1) {
    if(value == "Not yet started") {
      //Protect column C in that row
      var protection = range.offset(0, 2).protect();
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    } 
    else if(value == "In Progress") {
      var rangeC = range.offset(0, 2);
      var sheet = range.getSheet();
      var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

      for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
        var protection = protections[i];
        if (protection.getRange().getA1Notation() == rangeC.getA1Notation()) {
          protection.remove();
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}

function createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

You need to run the createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger function once to create the onEdit trigger that will run with your credentials.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events